# Printer is not printing

Tags: ubuntu, printer

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 and I tried to install my printer Samsung M2070 following this list of commands found on [this](https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/StampantiScanner/SamsungLinuxDriver) tutorial (that is unfortunately in Italian):

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

`sudo apt install suldr-keyring`

Then I used  [this](https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/supported.html) page in order to  look for the name of my printer and find my driver version. Then i typedd in terminal:

`sudo apt install suld-driver2-<version>`

Now I can see my printer in the printers application and if I try to print a pdf file I have the possibility to choose my printer. However it is not printing and it is like the printer didn't receive the "print" signal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your printer identification correct? I've been unable to locate information on a "Samsung M207O" printer.

Comment: @DavidYockey sorry, it's M2070, I've edited the question!

Comment: Can you print the test page? Are you sure you chose the correct driver in the printer setup?

Comment: @Fiximan no, the possibility to print the test page is not available

Comment: In terms of "unclickable" or in terms of "inexistent"?

Comment: @Fiximan in terms of unclickable

Comment: That means your printer is not yet set up. Did you actually add it after it being available as a printer.

Comment: @Fiximan the printer has already been added BUT what solved my problem was your suggestion though. Actually I add the printer again and remove the old one: now it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to deal with an unofficial repository such as SULDR, it might be best to install the driver from the official source and see if that works better.

The driver is available from https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2070-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16450377. (Note: HP purchased Samsung's printer business a couple years ago)

After uninstalling the SULDR stuff, download the driver from the link above, extract it, and then run the `install.sh` script found in the extracted directory. I don't know for sure, but logging out and back in or rebooting may be necessary after the install.

If you wish to continue attempting to install through SULDR, they have a forum that might help at https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/forum/.

Comment: How can I unistall SULDR? (Sorry this is my third week with Ubuntu!)

Comment: No prob. It's just like installing except you'd do `sudo apt remove ...` instead.

Comment: I did all the steps, but It still doesn't work. EDIT: I have removed and added again the printer and now it works!